# Why Tesseract for Android returns gibberish while using "equ.traineddata" to detecting Math symbols or equations?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

We hope to develop application to extract text from images and also extract and solve Mathematical equations
Achieved extract text from images using the Tesseract OCR Engine
But when we tried to extract the equations  from images the result was disappointing
We have been using version 3.01 We expected that is the cause of the problem
So we built the latest version of the Tesseract located in the repository https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two
We used the Official trained data files
eng.traineddata to detecting the text and this works fine and equ.traineddata to detecting math symbols and Mathematical equations,
but did not give the desired results .

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
protected String onPhotoTaken()
{
    // lang.traineddata file with the app (in assets folder)
    // You can get them at:
    // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
    // This area needs work and optimization
    boIsTaken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strTakenPicPath, options);

    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(strTakenPicPath);
        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

        int rotate = 0;

        switch (exifOrientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

        if (rotate != 0) {

            // Getting width & height of the given image.
            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

            // Setting pre rotate
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.preRotate(rotate);

            // Rotating Bitmap
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
        }

        // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
    }

    // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

    Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    Log.v(TAG, "initialize baseApi");
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    //getLang() returns equ in case of equations detection  
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, getLang());
    Log.v(TAG, "init baseApi done");
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

    baseApi.end();

    // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
    // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
    // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

    Log.v(TAG, "Detected TEXT: " + recognizedText);

    if ( getLang().equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
        recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
    }

    recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();
    return recognizedText;

    // Cycle done.
}//end onPhotoTaken
```

[image: image that contains equation And Tesseract result]

Answer (score 1):

That is because equ.traineddata it's a ******, i use eng.traineddata for numbers recognition. Maybe we need to train an own .traineddata for detecting math equations :S

If you find any .traineddata for math, better than equ, please let me know

Comment: Agreed.........

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract is trained to recognize a variety of fonts, and performs well especially on printed books. However if you use a font outside of its training set, chances are the results will be gibberish.

It's also very important to feed it images with a good contrast and even darkness in the background, because of the binarisation process, and [to make sure that the characters have a correct font size](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#Is_there_a_Minimum_Text_Size?_%28It_won%27t_read_screen_text!%29). Simply resizing the image can greatly improve results. 
You can take a look at [the Improving Quality page](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ImproveQuality) on the Tesseract wiki for more infos on that.

This is what the binarisation process looks like with a poor input image:

[image]

It could be a good idea to do some pre-processing in your application to compensate for the phone camera's quality before passing the images to Tesseract.

If you still can't get anything useful out of it, [you will probably need to train Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) to recognize those kind of problematic fonts manually.
The process is a bit involved, but it works wonders.

The results will not always be perfect, if the user takes a bad photo of illegible text, there's not much you can do about it, except automatically trying different training sets and pre-processing options until you get something that doesn't look like gibberish.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help me because I'm using The old English font

Comment: @user1854282 I believe that the "Improving Quality" points still apply. The photo you posted is unlikely to give good results, no matter what font. But I'd still suggest trying to train Tesseract with the specific kind of images you're using. I did that for a project of mine and went from gibberish to >99% recognition.

Comment: and I'm aware by what you mentioned above about image quality and font size .

Comment: but i think the main problem in the equ.traineddata file or the way that i deal with

Comment: Right. That's why I think that creating your own .traineddata file, by training Tesseract, may help with that. The equ.trainneddata is just an official training file, but if it doesn't work for you, you can make your own. At least, that's what I did. Good luck with your app!